# What is the point of Community resurrecting questions by unregistered users?

Tags: discussion

What is the point of Community resurrecting questions by unregistered users?

By definition they are never going to have accepted answers.

[Error in sudo code? E: Type 'sudo' is not known on line 2 in source list](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/120314/error-in-sudo-code-e-type-sudo-is-not-known-on-line-2-in-source-list)

Answer (score 7):

If you look at the [timeline](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/120314/timeline), you get a hint of what the purpose of this bumping is:

> This question has answers that may be good or bad; the system has marked it active so that they can be reviewed.

The point is *not* to have the author of the question accept the answer; the author isn't even notified when this happens. It's an indication to the entire community: please have a look at the answer and decide whether it's good or bad. (Or at the question.)

Right now, the question has a score of -1, which means [it won't be bumped anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184511/295232).

Comment: As further comment WHY do you bother to edit ancient closed posts e.g. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/36169/can-raspberry-pi-function-as-spi-slave. All this serves to do is annoy the few high rep users on this who can see closed posts. You would be better employed trying to stop Raspberry Pi Ltd. from changing/deleting their links w/o redirect.

Comment: All users can see closed posts, not just high-rep users. Most closed posts do have some value, if not [Roomba](/help/roomba) will take care of them. It's a script that edits those posts (it's active on the entire network) so it doesn't really consider the contents/topicality of the post. There's a rate limit (1 post per three days) in order not to flood the homepage and/or the review queue. Unfortunately, I have no influence at all on Raspberry Pi Ltd whatsoever, and there are [other companies](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/406565/4751173) with the same problems ...